# PHP process http request from one page and display it on another

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, inventory

I come here with very little knowledge on web development trying to learn, so I ask for some patience in regards to my ignorance on the subject.

It would be great if you could show me logical steps that i need to perform to complete the task before me.

Working with PHP here. I need to figure out how to send a GET request from one page/web application and process as well as display it in another.

A simple example:

there are 2 php pages, one to send the request - send.php, another to process and display it display.php

send.php contains a simple form to get some user input string and using get method to send it over to display.php

```
<form action="display.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="userInput">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

display.php receives the string and uses it as a parameter for some function and echoes it.

What logical steps do I need to perform to be able to open send.php in one window, display.php in another, type something in into the form, press submit and see the results in the display.php window instead of usual redirect to display.php from send.php? As far as I know, AJAX allows us to communicate with the server but the result is still returned to the same page. Forgive my ignorance, I seek the logical steps to the solution, maybe certain technologies or methods that I am currently unaware of,something to look into and find a way to accomplish this task.

Actual task is work with inventory management system: we need to be able to scan barcodes/id's etc. with one device, while seeing information about the items on another screen (think: scanning barcodes with an android app, sending it to the web based inventory system, which is open on a tablet computer or something like that and seeing the information about the item on said tablet).

Notes: we were explicitly told not to use java/scala, because the sys-admin doesnt want a jvm running on the same server as the inventory system(appearantly only one server dedicated to that), i assume node.js also falls into the same boat, although im uncertain.

Thank you for your patience dealing with a complete web development noob :)

Comment: This is basic HTML add this `target="_blank"` to your form tag.

Comment: @Daan I think it is more complex than that in that the OP indicates that they want to view updated data on one device based on input from another device.  You are basically talking about building a whole application that has an input interface and a reporting/management interface.  This is a problem of significant scope and way too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Webservices could take care of this issue.

Comment: so you pretty much want something like StackOverflows comment system. In SO's case, when a user comments on someone's posting, that someone sees that red message on the top navigation section of the page letting them know there are comments and so on.  In your case, you want to send the barcoded information to that other window correct?

Comment: just commenting here: `we were explicitly told not to use java/scala, because the sys-admin doesnt want a jvm running on the same server as the inventory system` well, javascript don't run in server, run on client machine. :P

Comment: its JAVA not javascript ;) and javascript can also run on the server like node.js

Comment: @MikeBrant exactly, i realize that im way out of my depth here, thats why im asking about the logic of comunication here. Maybe I can receive data from device on the server, temporarily store it, say in a file, set my display page to read from said file, put it as a parameter in my functions (as some sort of default to be taken on page load) and then reload page with that parameter to make it work? Im completely guessing here, really need guidance.

Comment: @Daan will look into webservices, anything specific to look for/learn?

Comment: @CodeGodie yes, i need to get barcode (app on mobile device already ahs extracted the number) and for user to see the results of the search(its used to query the DB). SO case i think is same/similar, someone from another page comments, other user sees the notification, in essence seems like the thing im looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after analyzing your OP(Original Post) more in depth, I believe what would work for you is the following:

In `send.php`: use Ajax to store each scanned barcode to the database. The reasoning for this is so that you dont redirect elsewhere. AJAX will just look for the php file that does all the storing work(which you can call process.php).

In `display.php`: retrieve all the barcodes from the database and render it. This can be done straight with embedded PHP or is you want to do this every so many times, use AJAX.

With this structure, you can see all the barcodes saved regardless of what window or device you are in.

Comment: this seems to solve my problems, thank you! Will go and implement it :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use websockets, and a server that supports it like node.js
https://www.websocket.org/demos.html

through php by a long polling
http://webcooker.net/ajax-polling-requests-php-jquery/

its also possible by using postMessage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: will look through demos/read up, might be just the thing, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I got you.

What you want is to, when the user click on submit, he opens at the same page, the `display.php` file without redirecting, to add new info, and then return to the `send.php` page?

Well, the way I see it, you can do it with some javascript and CSS.

Here is my solution (I mean, the way  would do it).

What you will need is to have a new `<div>` (or other tag) with an `<iframe>` inside of it, some JavaScript functions (they run at client side, not server side), and some CSS.

lets show ya how your `display.php` file should looks like:

```
<form action="display.php" method="get" target="display" onSubmit="load();">
    <input type="text" name="userInput">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="mydiv" class="hide">
    <iframe name="display"></iframe>
</div>
```

Notice that I wrote the target of the form equals the name of the iframe, so it will always submit to the iframe. And, into the form it will make a javascript call when submitting. Also, I've added a class at the new div to hide the content with CSS.
The CSS would looks like:

```
body, html{ /*to fix the page css*/
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#mydiv{ /*this is how it should work*/
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000; /*the position of the div relatively to other elements, to be always in front of them*/
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /*this will add an artistic background effect when loading the submit*/
}
.hide{ /*this class hide the element*/
    display: none;
}
```

And then your JavaScript:

```
function load()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    div.className = "";
}
function finish() //this will be called later, don't forget to give it parameters
{
    var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    div.className = "hide";
    //do what you need to show the final result here
}
```

now, at your `send.php` file, I believe you will have a form there, so you make a similar call at it. it should looks like:

```
<form onSubmit="submitForm">
    --your form contents--
</form>
```

and it should have a new javascript function, like:

```
function submitForm()
{
    parent.finish(); //this will call the iframe's parent function, don't forget to give it parameters and something to do.
    return false; //this will stop the submit and the 'refresh page'
}
```

and, then, you have your stuff.
I hope it works for ya.

Comment: I don't think this is what the Original Post is asking for. I think they want the results to be displayed dynamically (without refresh) in a completely different window/tab/ browser.. perhaps on a different device

Comment: this way is not refreshing. (unless you think the submit on the iframe is a refresh). it will open in the same window, but will work like 2...

Comment: What they need is the following: imagine you have two computers. CpA in Canada, and CpB in the US. CpA is on this url `site.com/send.php` and CpB is on `site.com/display.php` . When CpA submits the form, they want to display the results on CpB's screen without CpB having to refresh. (think of StackOverflow's commenting system)

Comment: sry, I don't see where he said that...

Comment: @GiovanniPerillo its not exactly what im looking for, CodeGodie has got my idea right. I need both pages("send" and "display") to be open at the same time, input something in the "send" page, press a button to send it, see it in "display" page. Im fine with page reload, as long as the "display" page is not redirected to from the "send" page.

Comment: ok... well, I think I don't know how to help now :/

Comment: Still, thanks for putting effort, i will try and examine your solution if not for my task, then for learning purpouses ;)

Comment: yeah, I agree, very well written answer

Comment: so you're ok with "refresh"? that shouldnt be hard at all.. why not try this: on send.php, use AJAX to store the barcodes to a database. On display.php, retrieve the barcodes from the database at load. Will that not work?

Comment: @CodeGodie that might actually work, i would need to set up some script to monitor database, so that whenever something is added (barcode) the page would refresh and perform needed operations! Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will work. Ill provide an answer.

Answer (score -1):

> What logical steps do I need to perform to be able to open send.php in one window, display.php in another

Try this:

```
<form action="display.php" method="get" target="_blank" >
<input type="text" name="userInput">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: He said `What logical steps do I need to perform to be able to open send.php in one window, display.php in another, type something in into the form, press submit and see the results in the display.php window instead of usual redirect to display.php from send.php?` so he don't want just to open in another window, he wants them to interact also.

Comment: not exactly what im looking for, opens the display page in a new tab, what i need is to have both pages open and one to be updated with processed information. Thanks for input though, didnt know about target attribute, learning something new already :)

Comment: @GiovanniPerillo correct :)